# Why do i have to include JS files in order to work with jquery in every single view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bundle

As the question says all about it but to give you a little more information i included all the `.js` files in my Asp.NET Mvc application like below:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Even that I have to include `.js` files in every single page in order to be able to work with jQuery else it doesn't work. I tried to include these script files in `BundleConfig` surprisingly the scripts where not working at all even on the layout page. What is the trick?!

Comment: Can you show us your code where you include `js.`files in your `BundleConfig` and how did you call bundled scripts in Layout? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general you have got an App_Start/BundleConfig.cs in your project

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static readonly string SiteJquery1Bundle = "~/bundles/jquery1";
    public static readonly string SiteJquery2Bundle = "~/bundles/jquery2";

    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        // We will choose bundle to render depending on IE version in view
        bundles.Add(new Bundle(SiteJquery1Bundle)
               .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"));
        bundles.Add(new Bundle(SiteJquery2Bundle)
               .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"));

    }
```

In your Shared/_Layout.cshtml view add:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
@Scripts.Render(BundleConfig.SiteJquery1Bundle)
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
@Scripts.Render(BundleConfig.SiteJquery2Bundle)
<!--<![endif]-->
...
</head>
```

So, default ASP.NET MVC projects adds _ViewStart.cshtml which defines single layout in every view. And check bundle registration in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    // ...
}
```